# Can Kinosearch do mathematical comparisons on numbers like "greater-than"?

Tags: perl, full-text-search, kinosearch

I am using Perl's KinoSearch module to index a bunch of text.

Some of the text has numeric fields associated with each word. For example, the word "Pizza" in the index may have a dollar field value like "5.50" (dollars).

How can I write a query in KinoSearch that will find all words that have a dollar value greater than 5?

I'm not even sure if a full-text search engine can do this kind of thing. It seems more like a SQL query.

Comment: My current plan is to iterate over the hit results manually and just prune out the ones that don't match my query. But something a little more general (and built into kinosearch) would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

After a bunch of searching (heh, heh), I found this [in the docs](http://www.rectangular.com/kinosearch/docs/devel/KinoSearch/Search/RangeQuery.html): RangeQuery

I may be able to make that work. But it appears the new required classes are not part of the standard release, yet.